# while loop not returning results PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

last night it was working fine now I am getting `undefined errors` for all my variables coming from the db. If I echo the variables after the `while` loop they are there but once they hit the `if` I get undefined errors.

```
   <?php 
   session_start();
   include "connect.php";
   include "report_errors.php";

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];


    $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM admin where username = :name AND 
            password = :password");

    $sql->bindValue(':name', $name);
    $sql->bindValue(':password', $password);

    $sql->execute();

   while($row = $sql->fetch())
   {
   $dbname = $row['username'];
   $dbpass = $row['password'];
   $dbemail = $row['email'];
   }

       if($name == $dbname && $password == $dbpass)
       {
         $_SESSION['loggedin'] = "yes";
         $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
         $_SESSION['pass'] = $password;
         $_SESSION['email'] = $dbemail;

         $url = "Location: yackimo_register_form.php";
         header($url);
         exit;
     }
         if($name == $dbname && $password != $dbpass)
           {
         $error = "invalidPassword";
         $url = "Location: login.php?error=$error";
         header($url);
         exit;
            }
```

Comment: **warning** you should hash your passwords in your db.

Comment: I know about the validation. This is just the backbone to get up and going

Comment: Did you try to print out the error? `PDO` probably offers some type of error reporting **(I use mysqli)**. `echo` it before and after `execute()`.

Comment: In Oracle, all returned columns end up as uppercase. I can't recall if MySQL does the same thing, but you might try displaying $row after you fetch it to find out. That is, change $row['username'] to $row['USERNAME']. If I knew the answer for sure I would write it as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: *"last night it was working fine now I am getting undefined errors"* - Surely something was modified. If "you" didn't modify/add anything, then something in your DB was added/modified. Things just don't stop working.

Comment: I think whats happening is when I enter login creds if one of the variables are not in the db it returns nothing making the variables in the `if` `undefeined`.

Comment: @rogerthat Then you need to add another condition to handle non-existant DB info.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes, just realized that

Comment: @rogerthat: You specifically state in your question that after the while loop, your variables are set, but now you're not sure? Please test that and amend the question accordingly...

Comment: @rogerthat I noticed the edit, however you didn't need to add that whole body of code, an `else{` with your header location would have sufficed.

Comment: @TomasCreemers they're defined if the db gets the right info. I need to code for non-existent db info. Don't know how I missed it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thats just one of the conditions to show what I was using the variables for

Comment: ah ok. "Roger that" ;-)  @rogerthat

Answer (score 0):

Which variables are you getting errors on? Seems like your problem is likely to be that you aren't returning any results with your SQL - therefore the variables are not being set.

Therefore - set the variables before the SQL loop to blank or something:

```
$dbname = null;
$dbpass = null;
$dbemail = null;
```

--edit-- or just put your `if` statement inside your `while` loop (if you're only expecting a maximum of one result...)